# How to display a presence validation conditionally in combination with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, carrierwave

I've an image model with the following validation

```
validates :image, presence: true, image_size: { width: { min: 400 },
height: { min: 400 } }, :file_size => { :maximum => 5.megabytes.to_i }
```

now I also have a carrierwave validation:

```
def extension_whitelist
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
```

When I submit a .txt file I get the following:

`The form contains 2 errors.
Image can't be blank
Image You are not allowed to upload "txt" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png`

The first error message shouldn't be there. Because I'm actually submitting something.

How to remove this first error message? `Image can't be blank`

Comment: The issue is Carrierwave acts _before_ the Rails native validation and it _effectively removes_ the image if it did not meet the conditions. I believe Carrierwave won’t allow the empty, so you might just remove the native Rails presence validator.

Comment: Understood. I still need it required for the end user to progress to the next step. Will use (working) solution of @mdesantis

Comment: I don’t follow. If it’s _empty_, you’ll never get to the next step, since Carrierwave will block it. I believe, the solution from @mdesantis is overcomplicated and should be avoided _if Carrierwave indeed disallows blanks itself_.

Comment: I've 2 form fields: details and image. If there are details added and there has been no image uploaded the user will progress to the next step. So the native Rails presence validator has to stay I guess, with the if statement from @mdesantis.

Comment: Do you mind to try to remove `presence: true` from your native Rails validator (only this key, `presence: true`) and commit with the empty image?  I am almost 100% positive, you’ll be not allowed to progress to the next step _by Carrierwave validator_. `presence: true` in native validator is a duplication of this functionality.

Comment: I'm my opinion is perfectly desirable disabling image validators when no image is supplied. Validating something that isn't even there doesn't makes much sense to me. Conversely, any error about presence image is nonsensical if image validations, which obviously require image presence, have been executed.

Comment: _I am almost 100% positive, you’ll be not allowed to progress to the next step by Carrierwave validator_

You are missing the point here: the objective is not only to mark the object as invalid, but also provide the right message to the user, and, why not, to developers too.

Comment: I've been working with the hints provided by both of you. The solution does work for the details page, but now the other pages are not working anymore. I've added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48120545/6430382

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could skip the presence validation if there is no image integrity error:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :image,
            presence: true,
            if: ->(record) { record.image_integrity_error.blank? }
end

user = User.new(image: File.open('tmp/.keep'))
user.valid? #=> false
user.errors.full_messages
#=> ["Image You are not allowed to upload \"\" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png"]
```