# How to correctly add the record.image_integrity_error to existing condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, carrierwave

History: [How to display a presence validation conditionally in combination with carrierwave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48098304/6430382)

I'm building an object with this gem: https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step

```
validates :name,      :presence => true, :if => :active_or_name?
validates :details,   :presence => true, :if => :active_or_details?
validates :image,     presence: true, image_size: { width: { min: 400 }, 
  height: { min: 400 } }, :file_size => { :maximum => 5.megabytes.to_i }, 
  if: :active_or_details?
```

with the functions:

```
def active?
  status == 'active'
end

def active_or_name?
  status.include?('name') || active?
end

def active_or_details?
  status.include?('details') || active?
end
```

how I set the status is:

```
params[:item][:status] = step.to_s
params[:item][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
```

The last step is 2 steps after the details page, so it should not be 'active'.

In the History (link above) you can read that I should be adding the following to the `if:` of the image validation:

```
-> (record) { record.image_integrity_error.blank? }
```

I tried to add the above line with

```
validates :image,     presence: true, image_size: { width: { min: 400 }, 
height: { min: 400 } }, :file_size => { :maximum => 5.megabytes.to_i },
if: :active_or_details? && -> (record) { record.image_integrity_error.blank? }
```

This causes the validation on the page to show only the 
`Image You are not allowed to upload "txt" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png`

But now the validation happens on each page of the before needed submission steps with `Image can't be blank`.

I tried to refactor the `-> (record) { record.image_integrity_error.blank? }` into the `active_or_details?` with an if/else statement. Then the `Image can't be blank` returns on the details page .

Please advise.

Comment: You could look into using `with_options` block. Here is some documentation [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#grouping-conditional-validations) and [API Dock](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options). Also I believe that multiple  `if` keyed conditions can be submitted as an `Array` e.g. `if: [:active_or_details?,-> (record) { record.image_integrity_error.blank? }]` although I have never actually tried it. Also `if: -> (record) { record.active_or_details? && record.image_integrity_error.blank? }` should work too in theory

Comment: Thanks. The `Array` solution works, as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#combining-validation-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment @engineersmnky: `if` keyed conditions can be submitted as an `Array` e.g. `if: [:active_or_details?,-> (record) { record.image_integrity_error.blank? }]`